# How do I pass a variable in element_to_be_clickable of WebDriverWait selenium modules?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parameter-passing

I have a problem about how to pass a string in element_to_be_clickable as variable

I would parametrize the string "input[class='loginTextEntry'][id='user']" in a variable named InputVar and pass it to element_to_be_clickable of WebDriverWait

For example for the following (working fine) instruction in python script

```
WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_TO).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class='loginTextEntry'][id='user']"))).send_keys(userinfo[0])
```

I would code it as :

```
InputVar = "input[class='loginTextEntry'][id='user']"
WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_TO).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
InputVar))).send_keys(userinfo[0])
```

But doesn't work

I have tried some other attempts:

```
InputVar = "\"input[class=\'loginTextEntry\'][id=\'user\']\""

WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_TO).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
InputVar))).send_keys(userinfo[0])
```

---

```
InputVar = "input[class=\'loginTextEntry\'][id=\'user\']"

WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_TO).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
\" + InputVar +\" ))).send_keys(userinfo[0])
```

But I didn't find any solution.
How could I code it ? That is important for me because the InputVar could point to different cases and I would automatize

Comment: try `InputVar = 'input.loginTextEntry#user'`

Comment: btw, what is the error you got?

Comment: The error is simply:
 NoSuchWindowException: Message: Window not found. The browser window may have been closed.

Comment: I doubt that problem is in the InputVar... Maybe you call `driver.closed()` before? Show all the code

Comment: No, the call to the driver.close() is done only after the instruction. 
Moreover, If driver.close() was before, then also the instruction without variable inputVar:
 -> WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_TO).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class='loginTextEntry'][id='user']"))).send_keys(userinfo[0])"
had finished in error. Instead that worked fine

Comment: But `NoSuchWindowException` is not about passing variables... Show the whole function and the error with traceback

Comment: SOLVED :
Something was dirty in editing file
because I put in external file the variable with value:

InputVar=input[class='loginTextEntry'][id='user']


So I uploaded the variable with a my simple reader 
and I executed the instruction in python code:

WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_TO).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
InputVar))).send_keys(userinfo[0])


It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Parametrizing the entire string **`"input[class='loginTextEntry'][id='user']"`** will be cumbersome. Instead I will suggest to write a `function()` which will take the variable **`myUser`** as an input argument as follows :

```
 def test_me(myUser):
        WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_TO).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class='loginTextEntry'][id='" + myUser + "']"))).send_keys(userinfo[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :
Something was dirty in editing file
because I put in external file the variable with value:

InputVar=input[class='loginTextEntry'][id='user']

So I uploaded the variable with a my simple reader 
and I executed the instruction in python code:

WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_TO).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
InputVar))).send_keys(userinfo[0])

It worked fine.